# Why is Pointer = NULL defined as clean code?

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

So my programming teacher told us, that if you don't use a pointer but like to declare it, it is always better to initialize it with NULL. How does it prevent any errors if i don't even use it?

Or if I am wrong, what are the benefits of it?

Comment: In general it is a good idea to initialize variables :-)

Comment: The benefit of initialising it even if you don't use it comes when you change the program and do use it. Of course if you dont ever use it, maybe it shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

De-referencing `NULL` is likely (guaranteed?) to cause a segmentation fault, immediately crashing your app and alerting you to the unsafe memory access you just preformed.

Leaving your pointer uninitialized will mean it still has whatever junk was left over from the previous user of that memory. It's entirely possible for that to be a pointer to a real memory region in your app. Dereferencing it will be undefined behavior, might cause a seg fault, or it might not. The latter is the worst case, which you should fear. Your app will just keep chugging along with whatever non-sense behavior resulted from that.

Here's a demonstration:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void i_segfault() {
    fflush(stdout); // Flush whatever is left of STDOUT before we blow up
    
    int *i = NULL;
    printf("%i", *i); // Boom
}

void use_some_memory() {
    int *some_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *some_pointer = 123;
    printf(
        "I used the address %p to store a pointer to %p, which contains %i\n",
        &some_pointer, some_pointer, *some_pointer
    );
}

void i_dont_segfault() {
    int *my_new_pointer; // uninitialized
    
    printf(
        "I re-used the address %p, which still has a lingering value %p, which still points to %i\n",
        &my_new_pointer, my_new_pointer, *my_new_pointer
    );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    use_some_memory();
    i_dont_segfault();
    
    i_segfault();
}
```

Comment: Not guaranteed for sure. Moreover, the address `0` on some systems might be even a valid address to access. Well, in this cases NULL *should* be defined by some other means, but in practice it does not happen.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But on those systems, would `NULL` still be `0`? Or would it be some other, equivalent value that's intentionally not dereferencable?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am saying, it *should* not be, but the toolchains used are usually generic and have just this common `NULL` definition.

Comment: Oh I missed that edit. That's interesting, and disappointing to hear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure dereferencing null is the same undefined behavior as dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  The only difference is that it's easy to check if its dereferencable.

Comment: if `NULL` or `0` is assigned to a pointer, the compiler is required to fill it with some invalid value that may or may not actually be 0 under the covers.  Likewise, comparisons with `NULL` or `0` will always compare against the invalid value.

Comment: But even within the broad category of "undefined behavior", there are distinctions that can be made. I.e. there's a difference between dereferencing a pointer that points to the the approximate "neighbour hood" of your processes real addresses, versus one that's "way out there" which is almost certainly not mapped to your process, and will cause the OS to seg fault you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: A null pointer has a **valid** value; it is entirely allowed and defined for the value of a pointer to be a null pointer. It is a value guaranteed to compare unequal to any pointer to any object or function.

Comment: I don't imagine NULL ever not being defined as 0 unless naively redefined by hand, some programs or sanity checks that rely on NULL being 0 would break. Even if it doesn't segfault, pointers assigned to zero or NULL can be checked by assertion or if statement, whereas undefined pointers cannot. Personally I prefer assigning zero over NULL to be sure.

Comment: I think what you can say is that *many* commonly used implementations will cause a segfault on *most* attempts to dereference a NULL pointer.  Which is still extremely useful, even if it's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to make sure your program does not use an uninitialized pointer:

- You can design and write your program carefully so that you are sure that program control never flows through a path that uses the pointer without initializing it first.
- You can initialize the pointer to `NULL`.

The first can be hard, depending on the program, and humans keep making mistakes with it. The second is easy.

On the other hand, the second only solves one problem: It ensures that if you use the pointer without otherwise initializing it, it will have an assigned value. Further, in many systems, it ensures that if you attempt to use that value to access a pointed-to object, your program will crash rather than do something worse, like corrupt data and produce wrong results or erase valuable information.

That is a useful problem to solve, because it means this bug of failing to assign the desired value is likely to be caught during testing and, even if it is not, the damage is may due is likely to be limited. However, this does not solve the problem of ensuring that the pointer is assigned the desired value before it is used. So, like many of these code recommendations, it is a useful tip to help limit human errors, but it is not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

I'm still not sure on what the point of these pointers is. How could you use an uninitialized pointer in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize a variable (by mistake) the problem is that your program can be even more anomalous than normal.  Imagine you have declared an `enum` with the values `ONE`, `TWO`,  `THREE`, and you forget to initialize it, and at some point you include the following code:

```
switch(my_var) {
case ONE: /* do one */
    ...
    break;
case TWO: /* do two */
    ...
    break;
case THREE: /* do three */
    ...
    break;
}
```

and you can get nuts because you assume that, at least one of the possible values of the type should be executed... but that's simply not true, as the variable has not been initialized and the value doesn't need even to comply with the constraints imposed to the data type it represents.

Initializing a variable can introduce a short couple of instructions in your code, but it saves a lot of nightmares when searching for errors.

In the case of an uninitialized pointer, the case is worse, as many programmers `free()` memory allocated from the heap based on the test

```
if (var) free(var);
```

and most probably an uninitialized automatic variable of pointer type will point somewhere, and sill be tried to be `free()`d.